# How to correctly implement the spring java dto class?

Tags: java, json, spring, api, dto

How to correctly implement the dto class so that when you get the json, there is no need to parse it ?

For example, for such a json object:

```
{"errorCode":"0","errorMessage":"Success","actionCode":71015,
"actionCodeDescription":"Operation declined. ",
"amount":100000,"date":1618750705018,
"OrderParams":[{"name":"Finish","value":"false"}],
"attributes":[{"name":"number","value":"6a883ef0"}],
"cardInfo":{"pan":"111111**1111","expiration":"202202"},
"id":"123456","auth":"110101010"}
```

from it you need to get the values of the keys:
actionCode , amount, date , pan

Update

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class OpenJsonFormat {
    
    @JsonProperty("actionCode")
    private String actionCode;
    
    @JsonProperty("amount")
    private String amount;
    
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date date;
 
    @JsonProperty("pan")
    private String pan;
  

}
```

Comment: You don't need to add `@JsonProperty` for those variables whose name is identical to corresponding field name in JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring just  create a class with all these fields (and same names of the fields) and use it as parameter in your controller method

Like here even though RequestBody is optional https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Example from one of my spring projects(look for post methods): https://github.com/asgarov1/universitySchedule/blob/master/src/main/java/com/asgarov/university/schedule/controller/CourseController.java

Comment: import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class OpenJsonFormat {
 @JsonProperty("actionCode")
 private String actionCode;
 @JsonProperty("amount")
 private String amount;
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
 private Date date;
  @JsonProperty("pan")
 private String pan;
}   this way you can do ?

Answer (score -1):

just create tow class entity and dto class
like this

this entity class

```
    class EntityFoo{
        int id;
        string name;
        //create setter and getter  

// in this method translate from dto to entity

        public EntityFoo toEnity() {
            DtoFoo dto=new DtoFoo();
            dto.setId(this.id);
            dto.setName(this.name);
            return dto;
          }
    }
```

and the dto class

```
    public DtoFoo(){
        int id;
        String name;
        //create geeter and setter

// in this method translate from entity to dto
        public EntityFoo toDto() {
            EntityFoo entity =new DtoFoo();
            entity.setId(this.id);
            entity.setName(this.name);
            return entity;
        }
    
    }
```

and this is link in github i am used dto and entity https://github.com/abdalrhmanAlkraien/Spring-Book-Repo

or you can use mapstruct interface to translate dto to entity or entity to dto

Comment: It's easier to read code that's well formatted. Please help other read your code :)

Comment: show new edit for example and use this class into servies when post method take dto parameter and translate to entity and when get method take entity parameter   and translate to dto and check this project into get hub i am used dto and entity  https://github.com/abdalrhmanAlkraien/Spring-Book-Repo